# Finding first and second maximum and their locations

Tags: r

everyone
I am new to R. I would like to find out the first and second maximums and their locations, using R studio.
It would be appreciate if you could help me how to do that.

Example explanation:

[image: Example trend]

I would like to find the two maximums (before and after depression - lowest value). In this picture, the first maximum will be 17 before the depression (lowest value), and the second maximum will be 16 after the depression (lowest value). Also, I would like to find out their locations on x-axis. The first maximum 17 will be on 5, and the second maximum will be on 11.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will help if you can make your post reproducible by including some sample data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info on how to construct a high quality post to get good help on your problem.

Comment: Are you just interested in the top two `y` values and the corresponding `x` values at which they occur?

Comment: Yes, I would like to get top two y values and their corresponding x values. @DanAdams

Comment: Assuming a dataset `d <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = runif(20, 5, 20))`, you can just use `d[order(d$y, decreasing = T)[1:2],]` which basically sorts in decreasing order by `y` and returns the top `2` rows.

Comment: But, in my dataset, some top two y-values are on the same side of the depression. I would like to get one top y-values before the depression (lowest point) and another top y-value after the depression.

Comment: Ok that's more complicated. Please edit your question by clearly explaining your criteria and add some sample data. You need to be pretty explicit about how you would mathematically define the 'depression'.

Comment: I am sorry I made you confused. I already edited my post. Thanks, @DanAdams